# How to reduce font size of all element of DOM?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

Is it possible to reduce the size of all element of DOM by a specific value?

I am using bootstrap style now.
Like for h5 it is 14px and I need 12px, for h1 it is 36px and I need 34px so on.

I have 2 options to do it

1. To rewrite a custom css for all element. It needs a huge change.
2. Using jQuery. I need to traverse all element of DOM. Find out there
   font-size and reduce it by 2px. It will slow down page load time.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: In LESS you could do it, but otherwise i don't believe you can. In jQuery you can do it if you select all elements, filter it on css property and then set font-size to -2px;

Comment: @NielsVermeiren, already I have given that option in question. To do that I need to traverse all DOM element , which is not good.

Comment: your first one is an easy solution. target h1,h2,h3 etc by body .. give them !important specificity if want to override ie if you are using sass  body { h1{ font-size: 34px; } }

Comment: Just an idea: 
1) multiline select on font-size, select only number and add - 2 and copy
2) paste in excel and do them math
3) paste back

OOrrr something similar

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can set a base font-size for your `body` in **[rems](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/)**.

Meaning, you have to set a `font-size` property for your body like so:

```
body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

After this, a `rem` unit becomes equal to your base font-size:

`1rem` = `10px`

Therefore, you need to set the `font-size` of all your elements to `rem`'s.

When you want to scale everything down or up, simply change the `body` `font-size` property and it will scale everyting else accordingly.

> Thus, the units become relative.*

If you want to go down the JS ways, you can use a plugin like **[FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)** or some other alternative.